# Django Project - posts from a json file are not rendering in the browser

Tags: html, json, django, shell, view

As part of a Django project, I am trying to retrieve the contents of a json file (which is the project directory where the manage.py file is) and display them in the browser along with other posts.

I have followed these instructions in the shell, with no errors, so it should have saved.

**Shell commands**

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import json
>>> from socialmedia.models import Post
>>> with open('posts.json') as f:
...     posts_json = json.load(f)
...
>>> for post in posts_json:
...     post = Post(title=post['title'], content=post['content'], author_id=post['user_id'])
...     post.save()
```

However, on running the server, the posts are not displayed on the page.

**Update:** I did see a comment that suggested that this failure to upload/render posts from json could be related to the **id numbers of the posts.** I did, earlier, delete posts with id=1 and id=2 etc, so they are no longer there. I don't know how to rectify this issue, if this indeed is the cause of the problem. A clear explanation of next steps would be useful in an answer. What I have tried (with a resultant syntax error) is at the bottom of this question.

This is the code in the **home.html** page

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>Fakebook</h1>
    {% for post in posts%}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"}}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

and this is the relevant code in the **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .models import Post #import the Models Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)

from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post #what model to query in order to create the list
    template_name = 'socialmedia/home.html' 

    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

The json file is

**posts.json**

stored in the pseudofacebook directory along with manage.py

It's format is as follows:

**posts.json**

```
[
  {
    "title": "My Updated Post",
    "content": "My first updated post!\r\n\r\nThis is exciting!",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "A Second Post",
    "content": "This is a post from a different user...",
    "user_id": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "Top 5 Programming Lanaguages",
    "content": "Te melius apeirian postulant cum, labitur admodum cu eos! Tollit equidem constituto ut has. Et per ponderum sadipscing, eu vero dolores recusabo nec! Eum quas epicuri at, eam albucius phaedrum ad, no eum probo fierent singulis. Dicat corrumpit definiebas id usu, in facete scripserit eam.\r\n\r\nVim ei exerci nusquam. Agam detraxit an quo? Quo et partem bonorum sensibus, mutat minimum est ad. In paulo essent signiferumque his, quaestio sadipscing theophrastus ad has. Ancillae appareat qualisque ei has, usu ne assum zril disputationi, sed at gloriatur persequeris.",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Sublime Text Tips and Tricks",
    "content": "Ea vix dico modus voluptatibus, mel iudico suavitate iracundia eu. Tincidunt voluptatibus pro eu? Nulla omittam eligendi his ne, suas putant ut pri. Ullum repudiare at duo, ut cum habeo minim laudem, dicit libris antiopam has ut! Ex movet feugait mea, eu vim impetus nostrud cotidieque.\r\n\r\nEi suas similique quo, his simul viris congue ex? Graeci possit in est, ne qui minim delectus invenire. Mei ad error homero maluisset, tacimates assentior per in, vix ut vocent accusata! Mei eu inermis pericula patrioque? Debet denique sea at, ad cibo reformidans theophrastus per, cu inermis maiestatis vim!\r\n\r\nUt odio feugiat voluptua est, euismod volutpat qualisque at sit, has ex dicit ornatus inimicus! Eu ferri laoreet vel, dicat corrumpit dissentias nec in. Illum dissentiunt eam ei, praesent voluptatum pri in? Ius in inani petentium, hinc elitr vivendum an vis, in vero dolores electram ius?",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Best Python IDEs",
    "content": "Elit contentiones nam no, sea ut consul adipiscing. Etiam velit ei usu, sonet clita nonumy eu eum. Usu ea utroque facilisi, cu mel fugit tantas legimus, te vix quem nominavi. Prima deserunt evertitur ne qui, nam reprimique appellantur ne.",
    "user_id": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Flask vs Django - Which Is Better?",
    "content": "Ei dicta apeirian deterruisset eam, cu offendit invenire pri, cu possim vivendo vix? Nam nihil evertitur ad, ne vim nonumy legendos iracundia. Vix nulla dolorem intellegebat ea? Te per vide paulo dolor, eum ea erant placerat constituam? Dolores accumsan eum at.\r\n\r\nInteresset consequuntur id vix. Eam id decore latine, iusto imperdiet ei qui. In ludus consul reformidans eam. Nec in recusabo posidonium, cu tantas volumus mnesarchum pro. Nam ut docendi evertitur, possim menandri persecuti ne sed, cum saepe ornatus delenit ei?\r\n\r\nIn mel debet aliquam. In his etiam legere, doming nominavi consetetur has ad, decore reprimique ea usu. Eam magna graeci suavitate cu, facete delenit cum ne. Ponderum evertitur tincidunt ei mel, ius ei stet euismod docendi.",
    "user_id": 2
  }
]
```

As mentioned, the interactive shell appeared to accept all commands and did not throw up any errors.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot and did not find any questions with solutions on stackoverflow for this specific problem.

Update: What I have tried:

If no user is returned for id 1 and 2 (as is the case in my situation), I tried to create a new user with the :

**I tried this: (in the shell)**

```
User.objects.create_user(username='missing', email='missing@email.com', password='testing321', id=<1>)
```

**Error resulting:**

```
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

**On request, Post model (models.py in socialmedia)**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone #don't forget to add this
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 



    def __str__(self): #create a dunder underscore method to return strings in the view (instead of objects)
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Is anything rendered at all, like the `<h1>Fakebook</h1>`?

Comment: Yes, the h1s and everything else is fine. In other words, everything is rendered - just the old posts in the admin panel....not the new posts from the json file. Everything else is working absolutely fine with no errors on running the server.

Comment: Are the new posts shown in the admin?

Comment: No...Good question. They are not.

Comment: Can you show your `Post` model?

Comment: just updating question ..with models.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193147/discussion-between-daniel-hepper-and-misscomputing).

Comment: Please post an answer if you have one. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer. If you join the chat I'll try to help you figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

Found one part of the answer, but the posts are STILL NOT RENDERING:

I have managed to add an id and object for id 1 and 2 which were missing.

```
**(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.get(id=1)
<User: missing1>
>>>**
```

First of all, in the shell, when you are creating a new user don't forget to first **import the following**: (without which User will not be recognised)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Then, the **syntax error** was a <> in the id, instead of just using the integer.
I used id=<1> instead of just id=1

Full shell list of command used to solve the problem:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> user=User.objects.create_user(username='missing1',email='missing1@gmail.com',password='testing123',id=1)
>>> user.save()
>>> User.objects.get(id=1)
<User: missing1>
>>> User.objects.create_user(username='missing2', email='missing2@email.com', password='testing321', id=2)
<User: missing2>
>>> user.save()
>>> User.objects.get(id=2)
```

I'm hoping someone else can provide part 2 and the whole answer such that I can get the posts to render.